# Problems with sending data to my RV adapter, how I can solve it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make attaching files to some messages at my app. I have managed to do it, but my method is based on custom RV with adapter to which I send the list of folders and files. I decided to use `onActivityResult`. I have made smth like that:

```
public void showDialod() {
        if (isReadStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
        } else {
            isReadStoragePermissionGranted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 7) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                convertFileToString(ImageFilePath.getPath(this, selectedImageUri));
                Log.i("m", ImageFilePath.getPath(this, selectedImageUri));
            }
        }
    }
```

in general my array is filled with all important data but I can't show attached files after changing the method of attaching files. Here is the code of my method for showing attached files:

```
private void getImages() {
        mNames.clear();
        adapter.updateNames(mNames);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Objects.requireNonNull(draft_files).size(); j++) {
                    mNames.add(draft_files.get(j));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                }

                adapter = new AttachedFileAdapter(mNames, getApplicationContext());
                adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < ms.getArray().size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject object = ms.getArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ms.getArray().size(); i++) {

                JsonObject object = ms.getArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


        }
    }
```

as I see I don't send any data to my RV adapter and I can't understand why it depends on the method of attaching files. Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Once you done by creating Adapter, you don't need to create adapter again. Just update your `ArrayList` (like add, remove, update object from list) and use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to reflect the changes. 
Also you don't need to `setAdapter()` always. like

In `onCreate()`
1. Create recyclerView object 
2. Create List object 
3. Create adapter object by passing List

Whenever data changes:
1. Like new object added, delete or updated into arrayList then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`